# Spatial interpolation in PostGIS without outputting Raster

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, interpolation

I have some data that is similar to rainfall, ie. a latitude, longitude, and a Z number. It is in a point layer that is a nice clean point grid. Many Z numbers are missing in this grid.

I want to interpolate to find reasonable Z numbers. TIN, IDW,or other methods. I do not want to go into a Raster first then back out the intersections from the raster onto the point grid.

I can perform an interpolation in QGIS, but it generates a raster which I'm wanting to avoid. The goal is to perform all computation within PostgreSQL for production purposes.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is doable. However, you need to clarify your expectation on what to be outputted from the query. For instance, do you want to show it as polygon grids and output as geojson?

Comment: That seems feasible.  Do a join between each grid point and the data points, perhaps limited by a distance (use ST_WithinDistance).  Then compute the interpolated data value as the distance-weighted sum of the data values as in the IDW algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

A naive IDW implementation, from the top of my head:

```
UPDATE <points> AS itp
  SET  "Z" = (
    SELECT SUM(z/d)/SUM(1/d)
    FROM   (
      SELECT smpl."Z" as z,
             ST_Distance(itp.geom, smpl.geom)^<P-value> AS d
      FROM   <point> AS smpl
      ORDER BY
             itp.geom <-> smpl.geom
      WHERE  smpl."Z" IS NOT NULL
      LIMIT  <sample_size>
    ) sq
    WHERE  ipt."Z" IS NULL
  ) q
;
```

Where

- `<P-value>` is the factor applied to the inverse distance; you probably want to stay between `1.0` and `2.0`
- `<sample_size>` the amount of *(known) sample points* that needs to be considered in the *(k) nearest neighborhood*

*It's been a while since I had a look at the IDW algorithm, so this may need tweaking; the subquery `sq` returns the list of inverse distances (when used as `1/<distance>^p`), so you can go from there if you need to alter the actual IDW sums.*