# IDW inpterpolating PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a bunch of points with a temperature value in PostGIS stored as geom. How can I IDW interpolate between these and return a GeoJSON? I know how to return a GeoJSON from my points but I have no clue how to interpolate these. The points are in a table setup like this. I do not want it as a raster.

```
CREATE TABLE sources(
    id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    shortName VARCHAR(50),
    country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    countryCode VARCHAR(50),
    long VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lat VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    geog geography(point) NOT NULL,
    valid_from TIMESTAMP,
    county VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    countyId INT NOT NULL,
    municipality VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    municipalityId INT NOT NULL,
    value INT NOT NULL
);
```

[image: allpoints]

Comment: This answer suggests how to do a simple IDW on nearest points: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373241/14766

Comment: @dr_jts Is there a chance I can use https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_InvDistWeight4ma.html? However I don't understand what to put in it when I Have my points in geography

Comment: `ST_InvDistWeight4ma` is a callback function for `ST_MapAlgebra`.  You have to have a raster to use it.

Comment: @dr_jts Please look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431208/postgis-function-st-makeemptyraster-does-not-exsist I have problem creating raster

Comment: I hadent installed raster what a idiot I am